# Jquery selector only works in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html (rendered by ajax)

```
<div class="filteredItem" guildid="1">
  <div class="filteredItem_image" style="background-image: url(http://visitbrabant.nl.domainpreview.nl/dev/files/images/guilds/1_g1_1_1.jpg)" onclick="DoNav('?action=item&amp;sid=1')"></div>
  <div class="filteredItem_right">
     <div class="filteredItem_name">Park Hilaria</div>
     <div class="filteredItem_city">Eindhoven</div>
     <div class="filteredItem_duration">undefined</div>
     <div class="filteredItem_short">De Kennedylaan in Eindhoven weer in Park Hilaria. Het tijdelijke pretpark is veel meer dan alleen een kermis. Het is zomers topvermaak voor alle leeftijden.</div>
     <div class="addToList" onclick="addToList(1)"></div>
  </div>
```

This is the onclick `addtolist` function:

```
function addToList (GuildId){
$.getJSON('http://visitbrabant.nl.domainpreview.nl/dev/vb/inc/api/set.useritem.ajax/?gId='+GuildId+'&pId=0&eId='+eId, function( data ) {
    if(data.status == 'error' && data.error =='user is not logged in'){
        alert('TODO:gebruiker is niet ingelogd, opslaan in de cookie');
    }else{
        console.log(data.planned);
        console.log($('.filteredItem[guildid='+2+'] .addToList'));
        if(data.planned == 1){
            $('.filteredItem[guildid='+GuildId+'] .addToList').addClass('inlist');
        }else{
            $('.filteredItem[guildid='+GuildId+'] .addToList').removeClass('inlist');
        }
    }
});
}
```

When the following line is executed:

```
console.log($('.filteredItem[guildid='+2+'] .addToList'));
```

it returns the following rule in the console:

```
div.addToList, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".filteredItem[guildid=2] .addToList", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function…]
```

and when I call this in the browser console:

`console.log($('.filteredItem[guildid='+2+'] .addToList'));`

it returns the same but when I call this:

`$('.filteredItem[guildid='+2+'] .addToList')`

(in the browser console) IT WORKS FINE.

SORRY for my bad english, I hope you can help me anyway...

Comment: you're trying to read the log before you've added it to the list

Comment: its solved, for a strange reason the console.log was blocking the addclass&removeclass. now it works fine.

and you are right i changed it to 2 just for a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the log after you've submitted it to the list like this:

```
 function addToList (GuildId){
$.getJSON('http://visitbrabant.nl.domainpreview.nl/dev/vb/inc/api/set.useritem.ajax/?gId='+GuildId+'&pId=0&eId='+eId, function( data ) {
    if(data.status == 'error' && data.error =='user is not logged in'){
        alert('TODO:gebruiker is niet ingelogd, opslaan in de cookie');
    }else{
        console.log(data.planned);
        if(data.planned == 1){
            $('.filteredItem[guildid='+GuildId+'] .addToList').addClass('inlist');
        }else{
            $('.filteredItem[guildid='+GuildId+'] .addToList').removeClass('inlist');
        }
        console.log($('.filteredItem[guildid='+2+'] .addToList'));
    }
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU for some reason when i put the console log after the submit the whole thing works, even the add and remove class wich didnt work before.